# Como deve ser feita a página inicial de um site utilizando o CakePHP 3.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3

Como deve ser feita a página inicial de um site utilizando o Framework CakePHP 3.0 (3.0.3)? Esta página possui conteúdo dinâmico.

O que consiste esta página: É uma página de exibição de principais produtos e de categorias de produtos (ambos buscados do banco), e exibirá componentes da página (botões e menus) diferentes caso o usuário esteja logado ou não. Esta página deverá ser acessível sem qualquer passagem de parâmetro via URL (`http://localhost:8765/`)

O que tentei fazer:

Editei o template `Template/Pages/home.ctp` do `PagesController` (ambos gerados pelos `bake`), na documentação é dito que `PagesController` é opcional e para páginas estáticas (e é exibida quando acessado o endereço `http://localhost:8765/`).

O que deve ser feito para criar uma página inicial sem que esta página dinâmica seja ligado ao um `controller` que obrigatoriamente esteja ligado a uma entidade e tabela?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar [*Elements*](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#elements).

Não vejo problema algum em seu `PagesController` fazer acesso a dados de várias entidades para montar a *View*. Apenas certifique-se que você vai segmentar cada elemento da página inicial para facilitar a manutenção no futuro, visto que a página inicial é a que mais muda durante o ciclo de vida de uma aplicação Web.